# How to register multiple blocks

Tags: block-editor

I've used the `@wordpress/create-block` package to create a new `mandoe-blocks2` Gutenberg block plugin.

I've created:

- `./src/blocks/mandoe-hero/`
- `./src/blocks/mandoe-daily-sales/`

From [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/390722/3206), and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_4loYiEcbg), I've edited `./mandoe-blocks2/mandoe-blocks2.php` to have:

```
function create_block_mandoe_blocks2_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/mandoe-daily-sales' );
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/mandoe-hero' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_mandoe_blocks2_block_init' );
```

then run `npm run build`.

The plugin activates without errors, but when I use Gutenberg, the new blocks are not found.

Are there any other steps I need to take?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a console error `Uncaught ReferenceError: __ is not defined`.

I believe this is a string translation function in WordPress. I removed references to this and the blocks are available now.

Comment: I wonder how I would import that function?

Comment: If you're using ES6; you can do through `import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';` in your source files that are using the string translation function although if you're not expecting to translate the plugin into other languages, you don't need it. An example would be at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/code/edit.js